# Socket Disconnect call during iOS Suspend doesn't disconnect socket

Tags: ios, sockets

I am using [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/GCD) in my application. I have a few problems.

When the app goes to background, I like to close the socket. During Suspend applicationDidEnterBackground call, I execute the following code but it doesn't disconnect the socket. (I check this via connected host)

```
[asyncSocket setDelegate:nil]; 
[asyncSocket disconnect];
[asyncSocket setDelegate:self];
```

Once I standby the phone, despite my call, the socket is not closed. After 60 seconds iOS closes the socket since we are at background and things go back to normal but the sender lost 60 seconds of data. I am probably not using API correctly but it could also be an issue.

Rest of my code below for reference:

Initialization

```
 dispatch_queue_t socketQ = dispatch_queue_create("socketQueue", NULL);
 asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:socketQ];

 if(![asyncSocket connectedPort])
 {
    if (![asyncSocket acceptOnPort:WIFI_BOX_PORT error:&error])
    {
      NSLog(@"Problem with opening Port: %@", error);
    }
    else
   {
       NSLog(@"Port opened, waiting for connection");
    }
 }
```